# Remove Sublime text theme in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed Sublime Text Keymap extension and then uninstalled it but my vscode theme still looked like sublime text. How can I remove it completely? Thank you very much!
[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling Sublime text and reinstalling it

Answer (score 7):

The theme you're using is called **Monokai** (it's also the default theme of Sublime Text) and it is a default theme that is shipped with VS Code.

Unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to completely uninstall a default color theme. The only thing you may do is the **disable** it, such that Monokai will not show up in the "Color Theme" menu accessed via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

To disable the default Monokai theme:

1. Open the "Extensions" menu in the sidebar
2. In the "Search Extensions in Marketplace" search bar, type `@builtin`
3. Under the "THEMES" section, search for "Monokai Theme". Click the gear icon and select "Disable"

Here's a [link to the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_remove-default-color-themes) on how you can disable default color themes.

[image: Instructions]